# Facebook file sending inside chat, how works?

Tags: facebook, file-upload, chat

Someone knows how the file upload works in facebook chat? The file is preserved in the server or database and deleted only if the user deletes the messages?

Sorry if this question is a little stupid.

Thanks!

Comment: If El Goog doesn't get you this info, you'd probably have to ask Facebook directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise frameworks like Facebook usually store the file in the server database so long as there is an existing reference to the file. If a file is sent from A to B, the file will exist so long as the message containing the file exists.